# Typing an if $_POST breaks page?

Tags: php, html

I have two pages one with the form submission and the other for the `PHP` code. I have a h1 heading written in the PHP file and works just fine. However when I add my `if ($_POST['submit']){}` statement the page doesn't display anything at all including the code that came before the statement? I have tried googling the issue but I was not able to find anything that seemed to relate. Here's my code:
for the `PHP` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
      echo "<h1>This is php!</h1><br>"
      if($_POST['submit']){
          echo 'form submited!';
      }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Then my form from my html page:

```
<form id="signUpForm" action="AddAcount2.php" method="post">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input id="uid" type="text" name="uid" placeholder="User Name"><br>
    <input id="password" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <button id="signUpFormButton" type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you're missing a `;` at the end of your echo statement. it's probably throwing an error, but you have errors disabled.

Comment: See my answer in the dupe.

Comment: I believe you have turn of error reporting and you have a error in ->  echo "<h1>This is php!</h1><br>" . Put a semicolon at the end

Comment: @mistermartin Not only that. The code doesn't even go till that.

Comment: missing semi-colon at the end of your `echo`.
try to check if your `$_POST['submit']` has a value e.g `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: Change the `<button>` to `<input type="submit" name="sendIt"`>

then 

    <?php
    
    if (isset($_POST['sendIt'))
    {
     echo "Form Submitted";
    }
    ?>

Comment: Thank you everyone! After checking all my semi-colons, it worked. Also @Praveen Kumar thank you for the tip on that, it was interesting and made more sense then the tutorials that I used to learn PHP.

Comment: @DakotaMiller You are welcome. These comes by practise and experience, not just following a tutorial. Glad that you came here and got it solved. `:D`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar and I learned something new! So double bonus.

Comment: @DakotaMiller Good to hear. And happy for you.